# Issue with datatables fixed header extension moving from correct position

Tags: jquery, button, scroll, datatables, fixed-header-tables

I am having trouble using datatables and the fixed-header entension together. The problem arises when a floating div interacts with the fixed header causing the fixed header to move away from the head of the table and display the header twice.

This appears like a glitch in the page althought it corrects itself once the user scrolls the mouse again.

The Code for div with buttons:

```
<div id="container_btn_float" class="btnContainer" style="position:fixed; z-index:110; top:50px" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <!--<label class="">Approve &nbsp &nbsp</label>-->
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btn_ApproveSelected" value="Approve">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_ApproveAll" value="Approve All">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_UnApproveSelected" value="Decline">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_ExpandAll" value="Expand All" onclick="expandAll()">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_ContractAll" value="Contract All" onclick="contractAll()">
                        <!--<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_UnApproveAll" value="All">-->

                    </div>

                   iv>
            </div>
```

The Code for the datatable is:

```
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(summaryTable, {
    });
```

The Code for the fixed div when scrolling (with buttons):

```
        jQuery(function($) {
          function fixDiv() {
           var $cache = $('#getFixed');
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100)
           $cache.css({
           'position': 'fixed',
           'top': '10px'
      });
      else
        $cache.css({
          'position': 'relative',
          'top': 'auto'
         });
       }

      $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
      fixDiv();
    });
```

Comment: I added a second div container with a button the same as the other buttons but I set its display to none and gave it some css so that it had an equal size to the div containing the divs which would eventually move and leave a space where it was initially placed.

Answer (score 0):

I added a second div container with a button the same as the other buttons but I set its display to none and gave it some css so that it had an equal size to the div containing the divs which would eventually move and leave a space where it was initially placed.

```
          <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="container2_btn_stay" style="height:76px;width:90px">
                  <!--Just some hidden text-->
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_HiddenBox" value="HiddenBox" style="display:none">
          </div>
```

Comment: secret is to retain the same height from top of page at all times.